# Group by columns + COUNT(*), how to get the average count for every combination?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, group-by

I have following (simplified) query:

```
SELECT     ResolvedBy, COUNT(*) AS Count, fiCategory, fiSubCategory, fiSymptom
FROM         tContact
WHERE     (ResolvedBy IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY ResolvedBy, fiCategory, fiSubCategory, fiSymptom
ORDER BY Count DESC
```

Now i need  the average count for every combination of `fiCategory, fiSubCategory, fiSymptom` as column. How to do that?

For example:

```
ResolvedBy    Count    fiCategory    fiSubCategory    fiSymptom    Average
    1           50         1              2             3            40
    2           30         1              2             3            40
    3           40         1              2             3            40
    1           20         2              3             4            30
    2           40         2              3             4            30
```

In the example are two combinations of fiCategory,fiSubCategory and fiSymptom: `1,2,3` and `2,3,4`. Hence there are two averages that are calculated:

1. 50+30+40 / 3 = 40
2. 20+40 / 2 = 30.

So i want to sum the count of every combination and divide through the number of occurences.

**Edit**: The example is an extraction of the desired result of the query. The count is the sum of all occurences of this combination for every `ResolvedBy`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: To help determine a solution, how are you arriving at the average?

Comment: Do you mean the average using the shown data? I.e., the average for fiCategory would be (1+1+1+2+2)/5 = 1.4?

Comment: It also might help to see what you would expect the output to look like.

Comment: In the example are two combinations of fiCategory,fiSubCategory and fiSymptom: 1,2,3 and 2,3,4. Hence there are two averages that are calculated: 1.combi => 50+30+40/3 and 2.combi => 20+40/2. So i want to sum the count of every combination and divide through the num of occurences.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Select ResolvedBy, [Count], fiCategory, fiSubCategory, fiSymptom
    , Avg(Z.Count) Over( Partition By fiCategory, fiSubCategory, fiSymptom ) As AvgByGrp
From    (
        Select ResolvedBy, Count(*) As [Count], fiCategory, fiSubCategory, fiSymptom
        From tContact 
        Group By ResolvedBy, fiCategory, fiSubCategory, fiSymptom
        ) As Z

Order By Z.Count Desc
```

Comment: There is no column `Count` and if i change it to `COUNT(*)` i get an exception: "Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause"

Comment: @Tim Schmelter  - Hm..You'll have to do it using a subquery. Will adjust to demonstrate.

Comment: Try removing `count` from the `group by`.  I added it for Thomas thinking that it was a column based on how he had it in the `SELECT` but I may have done more bad than good :(

Comment: @Abe Miessler - I believe you have to run the count in derived table first in order to get the counts for each group. Then you can run the average against that result.

Comment: @Thomas: i'll investigate a little to see if the result is correct but it's looking  good. Thank you :)

Comment: @Abe: Thank you also for your work and time. It gives the correct result. Impressing that people can understand and solve this without knowing the exact requirement and data.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT main.ResolvedBy, COUNT(*) AS Count, 
    main.fiCategory, main.fiSubCategory, main.fiSymptom, average
FROM tContact main
JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*)/count(distinct ResolvedBy) as average,
      fiCategory, fiSubCategory, fiSymptom group by 2,3,4) x
        on x.fiCategory = main.fiCategory
        and x.fiSubCategory = main.fiSubCategory
        and x.fiSymptom = main.fiSymptom
WHERE main.ResolvedBy IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 1, 3, 4, 5
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Comment: I get a "Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference".